# Unable to locate element through xpath

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm unable to write xpath for button new booking for below HTML :

```
<div class="mcf-button-extend -action-wrapper mcf-userfunctions">
   <a class="mcf-t1 mcf-button mcf-button-action" > new booking </a >
```

I have tried

```
driver.webelement("div [@class='mcf-button-extend -action-wrapper mcf-userfunctions"] /a [contains@class='mcf-t1']").Click().
```

Comment: What is your html code? It is not possible to advise anything unless we know the dom you're searching against.

Answer (score 3):

You should go through some basics tutorials to create an xpath.

For your element try below simple xpath :

```
//a[@class='mcf-t1 mcf-button mcf-button-action']
```

And if you want to find this based on some text in your xpath then

```
 //a[text()='new booking']
```

OR

```
 //a[contains(text(),'new booking')]
```

And  Its a link in your case then simply try using`linktext` selector